# New Child is not created in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to save new files in numbered order. so there is a count child it get updated but no new child is created
this is the code

```
 databaseReference.child("AdminList").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            long key= (long) dataSnapshot.child("count").getValue();
            databaseReference.child("AdminList").child("count").setValue(key+1);
            databaseReference.child("AdminList").child(String.valueOf(key+1)).child("uid").setValue(uid);
            databaseReference.child("AdminList").child(String.valueOf(key+1)).child("Aname").setValue(fname);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });``
```

Comment: Looks like you aren't creating a child anywhere. Find the answer below

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to store your data in a "continuous" manner, which is something that JSON objects just aren't designed do. If you are looking for an ordered list, use the priorities property, or you can order the data on the client side. This means that you can just store the data, and then either order client-side, or prioritize the children. I would look to do something like:

```
databaseReference.child("AdminList").child("uid").setValue(uid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `push()` to create new child nodes:

```
databaseReference.child("childName").push();
```